# Azure REST API - Is it possible to use existing Azure tenant users in php CMS and use and check their credentials remotely?

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory

**Situation background:**

We have company Azure with dozens of existing users with existing credentials for Azure access.

Beside that, we have CMS (in PHP) on separate webhosting (no relationship with Azure, not hosted under Azure).

**What we need:**

All existing Azure users will be able to access in our web CMS and we have dilema if CMS (php script) will be possible to check credentials remotely by requesting Azure API.

Or even better if user is already logged in Azure account and have active cookie (like in Facebook), CMS would only request some users details and check users tenant and domain and allow access automatically without any login form.

The best would be to combine both mentioned.

**The goal is:**

PHP script checking "Azure login cookie" (such as Facebook?) and ensuring communication with Azure API giving params like email and password and recieving true/false if some Azure user is exists for given credentials.

---

Appreciate any help and tips, regards, Jan.

Answer (score 0):

The is no such Azure AD API that provide the service to check the credential. And the flow describe above that require users enter their Azure AD credentials in you apps which is more like Phishing which is easy to leakage the users credential.

If you want to authenticate your apps via Azure AD, you can using the [OpenId connect](http://openid.net/connect/) stand protocol. Here is the authentication flow using the OpenId connect for your reference:
 [image]

More detail about authorizing access to web applications using OpenID Connect and Azure Active Directory, you can refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code/).

Comment: Thank you for advice, do I undestand it well if the process you described would be:
1) register app in Azure and add permissions to Win. Azure AD API
2) in CMS prepare Sign-in request with App ID and other params and redirect uri will be CMS URL
3) process response in CMS and allow or disallow user to access in
----
Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you were correct. And since you were developing PHP, I also suggest that you research the component which support OpenId connect protocol to help integrate the app with Azure AD.